# Story about an endless source of meat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story at some time in the 1990s which featured a regenerating organism which was used for meat.  Workers would carve the meat off of it.

They may have sent the meat through a pneumatic tube style system.  I recall that one of the characters was in charge of the organism, and had to be careful about how fast it regenerated.

Comment: http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0326.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like the dystopia [The Space Merchants](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1159) by Frederik Pohl and C. M. Kornbluth (1953), where a chicken heart of monstrous size, nicknamed Chicken Little, was cultivated for meat that was periodically trimmed off. The novel was originally serialized in *Galaxy*.

Comment: This is the one I was thinking of, but I hadn't managed to dig it up yet.

Comment: This is it!  I think I must have read an adapted or abridged version of part of the story, as part of an anthology

Comment: Nicknamed Chicken Little by the workers, but branded as Reel-Meet™!

Answer (score 3):

The BBC's Torchwood (a pseudo-apin-off of Doxtor Who) had an episode like this in season 2, episode 4, '[Meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat_(Torchwood))'.

> *The team investigates a meat company whose product seems to be extraterrestrial in origin. Jack makes the requisite bad innuendo puns about "eating alien meat". By complete coincidence, the meat is transported by... Rhys' company. Gwen doesn't like that at all, because inevitably, Rhys follows them and finally learns what Gwen does for a living.*
> <sub>[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TorchwoodS2E4Meat)</sub>

The meat company had captured an inter-dimensional 'space whale' and were keeping it alive while carving off sections to sell as local meat product.